# Why does this happen in Photoshop (CS5) when repeating patterns?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to create tileable pattern from a background that I created.

[image: example]

The left side of the image: created with layers (gradient fill, pattern overlay)

The right side of the image: created by repeating a 8px wide slice from the left side and repeated. You can see a slight but irritating banding at the edge of each slice. Why does this happen? Is there a solution?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is caused by layer styles. If you copy a part of layer, it also copies the style of it. Now if you paste that part, it will calculate the layer styles again, but from the edge of the new image.
Hard to explain, but i hope you get what i mean.

Now the solution:
When i hard copy(all the layers) 8 pix wide and set it as a patter from the left image, i do not get this irritating banding.

How to do this:
select the part that you want to make a pattern off. (the 8 pixel wide and X pixel high part)
Press CTRL + SHIFT + C (this will not copy 1 layer, but all that are vissible and combine it).
Press CTRL + N, then CTRL + V (meaning new file, paste.
Press CTRL + A (select all) and go to edit > define pattern.
Give the pattern a name.

Now fill any selection you want with you pattern and the banding is gone.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I must tell you, that's the exact way I tried this before and the result does produce that banding.

What I'm trying to do is create a repeating pattern for the footer, if you did find a way around it and can provide me a jpeg (8px x 14px) that did the trick for you that would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.lovebomb.nl/pattern.jpg -  there you go

Comment: That's a ton man, looks the issue is the 'effect' messing up at the ends. Slicing a 8px piece in the middle solved the issue.

Comment: For the ultimate in lightweight web backgrounds, keep in mind that Photoshop has "Single Column" and "Single Row" selection tools under the Marquee tool, allowing you to select a one pixel wide column from your graphic, and reducing the size of the image by 87.5 percent.

Comment: That is also caused by the layer style since the dropshadows etc are calculated fromt the edge. Is your problem still not solved since it is not marked as the right answer?